# String to date time conversion fails on hosted apllication on IIS

Tags: asp.net, datetime, iis, ms-access-2007, oledb

I have a asp.net application with MS Access database with ole db connection. On debugging the solution with IIS, when selecting a value from database and converting it to date time i will change the date time format from "dd/MM/yyyy" to MM/dd/yyyy and throw an error? Please suggest a solution for this?

```
strQuery += " WHERE (CDate(Shift.[ShiftDate])>=CDate('" + new DateTime(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month, 1).ToShortDateString() + "') and CDate(Shift.[ShiftDate])<=CDate('" + new DateTime(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString() + "'))";
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: strQuerey += "   WHERE (CDate(Shift.[ShiftDate])>=CDate('" + new DateTime(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month, 1).ToShortDateString() + "') and CDate(Shift.[ShiftDate])<=CDate('" + new DateTime(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString() + "'))";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you have different culture on your iis server and debug environment. Pass culture to parsing method.

```
DateTime.Parse(dateStringVar, new CultureInfo("en-US", false));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It is an ASP.net  application with Ms Access Database and my code is                 strQuerey += "   WHERE (CDate(Shift.[ShiftDate])>=CDate('" + new DateTime(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month, 1).ToShortDateString() + "') and CDate(Shift.[ShiftDate])<=CDate('" + new DateTime(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString() + "'))";
But the datetime formate changes while running with IIS.

Comment: Output string of ToShortDateString method depends on current stream locale. Most likely this is the reason of issue.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please suggest any solution for this

Comment: you can change locale of current stream or check if where any overload on ToShortDateString  with locale is input param.